# Some info about ACL in Joomla

Tags: acl, subscriptions

I've got a couple of questions about how ACL works in Joomla.
First of all, I would like to restrict access in certain categories only to users that are registered (some times paying a subscription). Is this achiavable in Joomla? How?
Second, can I give to some users the ability to write articles in specific categories, but not to automatically publish them? They are created in state "suspended" and only administrator can change the state to "published".
I'm willing to use K2.
Thank you.

Comment: Regarding the blog, check out Easy Blog, does everything you require.

Comment: Is it better than K2?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion @ufo however in my opinion, yes much better. They have a demo on their site you should check it out. Every component and extension will have pros/cons - it's about finding one that suits your needs, and paying for it if necessary.

Comment: Never used EasyBlog, but I once updated its Finnish translation, which required going over every feature and all of its UI. Lots of features, pretty good UI. Only real downside is that there isn't (wasn't) a free version to try, so there might be bit of leap of faith involved.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to restrict access in certain categories only to users that are registered (some times paying a subscription)

Yes, using third party extensions like Akeeba Subscriptions, you can allow only paid/registered customers to specific categories. This is done with the following method.

1. Create new user group in your user groups manager
2. Give the create permission of the category to above group
3. Setup Akeebasubs to assign this user group to the user after payment is made

> They are created in state "suspended" and only administrator can change the state to "published".

Joomla do not provide this feature by default, however third party components such as CjBlog adds this functionality to Joomla.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try with CjBlog. As far as you know, does K2 offers this functionality too?

Comment: I never used K2.